# Map need to be filter without tmst values

Tags: java, hashmap

In the below map, I have to remove key and values if key contains "tmst"

Input Map:

```
{"sun":"test", "row_mod_tmst":"10:05:20", "when" :"yesterday"}
```

Output Map:

```
{"sun":"test", "when" :"yesterday"}
```

I have tried like below, It is not working

```
 Map<String, Object> withoutTMST = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> (!entry.getKey().endsWith("tmts"))).
                    collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: In your filter it states: endsWith("TMTS")). There's 2 errors there: 1) it says TMTS, not TMST as it should. And 2) if you want this to match you have to make sure the casing matches as well, so in other words in your example json the TMST string is in lower case so your matching string should be as well.

Comment: It is typo error. Still it is not working

Comment: `endsWith("tmts")` should be `endsWith("tmst")`

Comment: Why `endsWith` when you said in your problem statement: `I have to remove key and values if key contains "tmst"`. Just use `contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just remove those entries from the map, instead of creating a new map object.

[`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) is a good candidate for this, applied on the map's `entrySet()`.

As for the removal condition, I would use `contains` in conjunction with `toLowerCase()`.

Here's the code for that:

```java
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains("tmst"));
```

**Input:**

```
{ sun=test, row_mod_tmst=10:05:20, when=yesterday }
```

**Output:**

```
{ sun=test, when=yesterday }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to filter `"tmst"` values.

Try this:

```
Map<String, Object> withoutTMST = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> !entry.getKey().matches(".*((?i)TMST)$")).
        collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(withoutTMST);
```

Output:

```
{when=yesterday, sun=test}
```

About regex:

- `.*` Matches any character
- `?i` Case insensitive match
- `$` End of line